# RPM upgrade post install exit

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Is there a way to exit from %post section in case of a upgrade RPM.

I have simple rpm with following sections.
NOTE: here I have exit in %post.

When I run rpm -Uvh package_name, there is an error encountered in %post section. The exit does happen only from %post section. However the rpm then continues with %preun and %postun section.

I just want to exit if there are any error in %post section.
Can this be achieved?

```
  %pre
  perform few checks here

  %post
  perform upgrade steps.
  If there is a error performing upgrade steps. **Then exit**

  %preun
  Perform pre-uninstall checks


  %postun
  Perform un-installation steps of previous package
```

Can someone clarify on this upgrade rpm package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atul.

I guess, you cannot abort rpm transaction in %post script let (script let
exit codes are ignored by RPM).

Comment: Right, I believe that should be the case. One cannot abort rpm in %post

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat unclear what you mean by exit: RPM exit? %post scriptlet exit?

Presumably, you wish RPM to stop an upgrade if you have a non-zero exit code in %post. That is already implemented: a non-zero return from %post will cancel the erase of the older package being upgraded.

The set of packages being upgraded will continue "best effort" however even if some package in the set fails.

Note that whatever files are installed in the newer package will overwrite paths: that happens before %post is executed, and so an exit in %post cannot stop what has already happened.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I was looking for complete RPM exit.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.Let me try and explain in better way.                    
I was looking for complete RPM exit. I have mentioned below code in my 
%post section                                                                            
                                                                                                                                       if [ $? != 0 ]; then
     echo "Copy Code: $? - Unsuccessful"
       exit 1
       fi
I just do not want the RPM to proceed with %preun and %postun section.  But the he rpm continues with %preun and %postun which I do not want

Comment: The "traditional" behavior in RPM checked the exit code of the install half of an upgrade and did not attempt the remove half of an upgrade (including running preun/postun  scriptlets if memory serves). I dunno what is currently implemented (but you have clearly seen that script lets are running).

Comment: The simplest workaround would be to test if some file was actually installed in %preun/%postun before running that portion of the script let. Basically write your own test to see if a package was installed